# Xcode 9 stuck on Swift 4 migration

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to migrate my Swift 3 project to Swift 4 in Xcode 9. After selecting target and choosing either of @obcj inference options, Xcode stuck on `Generating preview` spinning wheel forever. How can I migrate my project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the same conversion dialog uncheck `Remind me` checkbox and click `Convert Later`. Now go to `Build Settings` and change `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 4.0`. Most likely this will produce a lot of warnings or errors. Unfortunately you have to fix them manually.

Comment: Why did i even think that the automatic migration would work. It didn't from 2 to 3 either.